# How to convert multiple record updates into periodic snapshot in kusto

Tags: snapshot, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a mechanism that is posting an update to Azure Data Explorer each time a record changes at source. So the data end up as a series of versions of the record in ADX. I would like to turn it into a daily snapshot with the most recent version being used at the snapshot time.  I have managed to do something close with

```
let visits = datatable(id:guid, timestamp:datetime, category:string, start:datetime, end:datetime, row:int)
[
    "b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e", datetime(2021-10-01T01:02:03), "SRU", datetime(2021-09-30T01:02:03), datetime(null), 1,
    "b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e", datetime(2021-10-02T02:02:03), "SRU", datetime(2021-09-30T01:02:03), datetime(null), 2,
    "b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e", datetime(2021-10-02T02:05:03), "SRU", datetime(2021-09-30T01:02:03), datetime(null), 3,
    "b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e", datetime(2021-10-04T04:05:03), "SRU", datetime(2021-09-30T01:02:03), datetime(null), 4,
    "b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e", datetime(2021-10-05T07:05:03), "SRU", datetime(2021-09-30T01:02:03), datetime(2021-10-01T07:00:00), 5
];
let binsize = 1d;
let min_date_time = toscalar(visits | summarize startofday(min(timestamp)));
let max_date_time = toscalar(visits | summarize endofday(max(timestamp)));
//
range hour from min_date_time to max_date_time step binsize
| join kind=leftouter (
    visits
    | summarize arg_max(timestamp, *) by id, bin(timestamp, binsize)
    | extend hour = bin(timestamp, binsize)
) on hour
| project-away hour1
```

This gives the following:

| hour | id | timestamp | timestamp1 | category | start | end | row |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 00:00:00.0000000 | b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e | 2021-10-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 2021-10-01 01:02:03.0000000 | SRU | 2021-09-30 01:02:03.0000000 |  | 1 |
| 2021-10-02 00:00:00.0000000 | b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e | 2021-10-02 00:00:00.0000000 | 2021-10-02 02:05:03.0000000 | SRU | 2021-09-30 01:02:03.0000000 |  | 3 |
| 2021-10-03 00:00:00.0000000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2021-10-04 00:00:00.0000000 | b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e | 2021-10-04 00:00:00.0000000 | 2021-10-04 04:05:03.0000000 | SRU | 2021-09-30 01:02:03.0000000 |  | 4 |
| 2021-10-05 00:00:00.0000000 | b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e | 2021-10-05 00:00:00.0000000 | 2021-10-05 07:05:03.0000000 | SRU | 2021-09-30 01:02:03.0000000 | 2021-10-01 07:00:00.0000000 | 5 |

This is sort of right as it correctly picks the latest value (row 3) for 2021-10-02, however it doesn't pick row 3 for the following time period and we get blanks.

I'm stumped on the last part.

If it helps, the next part of the puzzle is to aggregate grouped on category resulting in something like

| day | category | total | started | ended |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | SRU | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-10-02 | SRU | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-10-03 | SRU | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-10-04 | SRU | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-10-05 | SRU | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for the first table, uncomment the last line to get the second table:

```
let visits = datatable(id:guid, timestamp:datetime, category:string, start:datetime, end:datetime, row:int)
[
    "b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e", datetime(2021-10-01T01:02:03), "SRU", datetime(2021-09-30T01:02:03), datetime(null), 1,
    "b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e", datetime(2021-10-02T02:02:03), "SRU", datetime(2021-09-30T01:02:03), datetime(null), 2,
    "b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e", datetime(2021-10-02T02:05:03), "SRU", datetime(2021-09-30T01:02:03), datetime(null), 3,
    "b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e", datetime(2021-10-04T04:05:03), "SRU", datetime(2021-09-30T01:02:03), datetime(null), 4,
    "b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e", datetime(2021-10-05T07:05:03), "SRU", datetime(2021-09-30T01:02:03), datetime(2021-10-01T07:00:00), 5,
    "8acaffa4-3ab8-479c-8f13-191c016bff70", datetime(2021-10-01T01:02:03), "SRU", datetime(2021-09-30T01:02:03), datetime(null), 6, 
    "8acaffa4-3ab8-479c-8f13-191c016bff70", datetime(2021-10-02T02:02:03), "SRU", datetime(2021-09-30T01:02:03), datetime(2021-10-02T07:00:00), 7
];
let binsize = 1d;
let StartDate = datetime(2021-10-01);
let EndDate = datetime(2021-10-06);
visits
| summarize arg_max(timestamp, *) by ['id'], Day = bin(timestamp,1d)
| partition hint.strategy=native  by ['id'] 
(
    make-series  timestamp = take_any(tolong(timestamp)) default=long(null),
                 start = take_any(tolong(start)) default=long(null),
                 end = take_any(tolong(end)) default=long(null),
                 row = take_any(row) default=long(null),total = count() default=long(null), 
                 started=countif(isnull(end)) default=long(null), 
                 ended=countif(isnotnull(end)) 
                 on Day from StartDate to EndDate step 1d  by category, ['id']
    | extend timestamp = series_fill_forward(timestamp), 
             start = series_fill_forward(start), 
             end = series_fill_forward(end),
             row = series_fill_forward(row),
             total = series_fill_forward(total), 
             started=series_fill_forward(started), 
             ended=series_fill_forward(ended)
)
| mv-expand timestamp to typeof(long), start to typeof(long), end to typeof(long), Day to typeof(datetime), row to typeof(int), total to typeof(int), started to typeof(int), ended to typeof(int)
| extend timestamp = todatetime(timestamp), start=todatetime(start), end=todatetime(end)
| project-reorder  id, Day, timestamp, start, end, row, category
//| summarize Total = sum(total), sum(started), sum(ended) by Day
```

| id | Day | timestamp | start | end | row | category | total | started | ended |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e | 2021-10-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 2021-10-01 01:02:03.0000000 | 2021-09-30 01:02:03.0000000 |  | 1 | SRU | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 8acaffa4-3ab8-479c-8f13-191c016bff70 | 2021-10-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 2021-10-01 01:02:03.0000000 | 2021-09-30 01:02:03.0000000 |  | 6 | SRU | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 8acaffa4-3ab8-479c-8f13-191c016bff70 | 2021-10-02 00:00:00.0000000 | 2021-10-02 02:02:03.0000000 | 2021-09-30 01:02:03.0000000 | 2021-10-02 07:00:00.0000000 | 7 | SRU | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e | 2021-10-02 00:00:00.0000000 | 2021-10-02 02:05:03.0000000 | 2021-09-30 01:02:03.0000000 |  | 3 | SRU | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 8acaffa4-3ab8-479c-8f13-191c016bff70 | 2021-10-03 00:00:00.0000000 | 2021-10-02 02:02:03.0000000 | 2021-09-30 01:02:03.0000000 | 2021-10-02 07:00:00.0000000 | 7 | SRU | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e | 2021-10-03 00:00:00.0000000 | 2021-10-02 02:05:03.0000000 | 2021-09-30 01:02:03.0000000 |  | 3 | SRU | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 8acaffa4-3ab8-479c-8f13-191c016bff70 | 2021-10-04 00:00:00.0000000 | 2021-10-02 02:02:03.0000000 | 2021-09-30 01:02:03.0000000 | 2021-10-02 07:00:00.0000000 | 7 | SRU | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e | 2021-10-04 00:00:00.0000000 | 2021-10-04 04:05:03.0000000 | 2021-09-30 01:02:03.0000000 |  | 4 | SRU | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 8acaffa4-3ab8-479c-8f13-191c016bff70 | 2021-10-05 00:00:00.0000000 | 2021-10-02 02:02:03.0000000 | 2021-09-30 01:02:03.0000000 | 2021-10-02 07:00:00.0000000 | 7 | SRU | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| b5ce180e-ce11-4936-b3f1-c817a261622e | 2021-10-05 00:00:00.0000000 | 2021-10-05 07:05:03.0000000 | 2021-09-30 01:02:03.0000000 | 2021-10-01 07:00:00.0000000 | 5 | SRU | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: I'm not sure it does, if you add two more rows to the dataset: //
    "8acaffa4-3ab8-479c-8f13-191c016bff70", datetime(2021-10-01T01:02:03), "SRU", datetime(2021-09-30T01:02:03), datetime(null), 6,
    "8acaffa4-3ab8-479c-8f13-191c016bff70", datetime(2021-10-02T02:02:03), "SRU", datetime(2021-09-30T01:02:03), datetime(2021-10-02T07:00:00), 7, then the numbers don't come out correctly.

Comment: Also, the question was about trying to fill in the blank row from the middle table; the addendum was about how I then plan on using this data.

Comment: You are right, I changed the answer to accommodate the two issues you raised.

Comment: James - did you give the updated question a try?

Comment: I did and yes it works. I'm mulling over whether to accept the answer though because it answers the "if it helps" addendum to the question and not the main question about "latest version of each  id for each time period" part.

Comment: Thanks James, did you try the last sentence suggestion "Remove the last line (summarize) to get the first table"

Comment: If you remove the last line you get integer columns of total, started, ended etc not datetime columns timestamp, start, end etc.

Comment: OK, I think I got it now, let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Yep, this one is exactly what I was after. Thanks for all your help.